# How to optimize and speed up current Magento SQL query?

Tags: sql, magento-1.9

How to optimize current Magento SQL query?

```
SELECT​ ​ customer_entity.email,​ ​ COUNT(sales_flat_order.increment_id)
AS​ ​ number_of_orders
FROM​ ​ customer_entity
LEFT JOIN​ ​ sales_flat_order​ ​ ON​ ​ sales_flat_order.customer_email​ ​ =
customer_entity.email
GROUP​ ​ BY​ ​ customer_entity.email
ORDER​ ​ BY​ ​ number_of_orders​ ​ DESC;
```

Comment: Share the statistics first. What is a data volume, what is expectation and what is current behaviour

Answer (score -1):

why even doing a Join if customer_email​ is present in the same table?

```
SELECT `customer_email`, COUNT(increment_id) as number_of_orders 
FROM `sales_flat_order` 
GROUP BY customer_email 
ORDER BY number_of_orders DESC;
```

Comment: I guess, OP wanted see data from customer_entity if no associated rows exists in sales_flat_order, hence, used left join

Comment: @samsonovits
Thanks, for the idea, but unfortunately then will lost customer emails who has no orders at all (not present in sales_flat_orderm but present in customer_entity)